# Give a name to the current window (using jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, window

I am in a situation where I need to give a name to the window where a site is getting loaded. Like, when I open StackOverflow.com, I should be able to give it a window.name so that I can use that later.

Any solution here ?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, actually I solved that using `window.name = 'my_fenetre';`. Was looking for "name", not "title". Thanks to all anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
$("html").addClass("myclass");
```

in future you can use this class to find the correct window

```
$("html").hasClass("myclass").something
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for:

```
document.title
```

This is both read and writable.

Answer (score -1):

or if you want to use jQuery you can do this:

```
$('title').text("My Title");
```